# Rest Client API design and implementation (with RestEasy)

Tags: java, rest, api, client

I am working on a design to create a generic rest client for our application for current and future integration's with multiple services (different external systems). Following is a high level diagram

[image: High level design]

I am thinking of creating a RestClient per external host, and Store them in a Map with Service name as Key and RestClient as value. Following is my RestClient(will be cached) class that wraps ResteasyWebTarget.

```
public class RestClient {
    private ResteasyWebTarget target;

    @Singleton
    public class RestClientRepository {
        private final Map<String, RestClient> repository = 
            new ConcurrentHashMap<String, RestClient>()
```

My default implementation will be using RestEasy. As my client code will be part of a webapp(multihtreaded environment). I will be using PoolingClientConnectionManager

```
ClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm);
ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(httpClient);
ResteasyClient client = ((ResteasyClientBuilder) ResteasyClientBuilder
  .newBuilder()).httpEngine(engine).build();
```

Is there a better solution than this approach?

Comment: I plan to build a similar generic rest client. I wanted to understand the key challenges in building such a client and did you consider using libraries like http://unirest.io/java.html or https://github.com/wiztools/rest-client or https://github.com/hamnis/REST-client/. Please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 2):

In the first place it seems to be right, but I think you want to hide these implementation details. Ask your self: where is the difference between a local database and some remote data servers?

You probably want to have a been for each resource like `User` and a store like `UserStore`. Each store has some methods for interaction like:

```
public User getUser(String, String)
public User getUserById(long)
public void updateUser(User) throws ...
public void deleteUser(User)
public void createUser(User)
```

This hides the implementation details of your REST API. And the details of caching locally and so on (if you want to cache locally you have to synchronize the data and doing synchronization correctly is very hard to solve!)

Comment: thanks for your reply.I absolutely agree with your suggestion. That part of design in completely covered. Point of concern is if RestClient per host is a good idea, also Synchronization is not a big worry for me. Would you suggest single RestClient for all hosts?, or the one i am working on.

Comment: The RestClient is only for creating WebTargets. So more than one client would be waste of resources, or am I wrong? Is there any argument to have more than one? I would create a map of String -> WebTarget if a WebTarget is cacheable.

Comment: Thanks, a good catch. The point for caching the RestClient is that the required filters, and other configurations are implied on this level. The RestClient i am caching has a Webtarget instaance wrapped in it (My apologies i should have posted the code in the first place). I have updated my original post.

Comment: Now I think I'm going to know what you want to ask, but one more question: One `RestClient` is for one `WebTarget`, and one `WebTarget` is for one URL, so for one REST resource? Does it make sense to call it `RestClient`? I would say a `RestClient` handles many resources or the whole communication between you application and one server.